# How to fetch the rows with in a date range?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a doubt with the sql query in php.During login  current date along with time is coverted to 'strtotime' a stored in database.The logout time also entered into the database.A person can login more than once in a day.

I want to list each user login time for last 7 days(Each day separately for each user) .I used the following query

```
"SELECT a.user_id, b.username, a.clock_in,a.clock_out , DATEDIFF(a.clock_in,a.clock_out) FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "clock_history a left join " . DB_PREFIX . "user b on a.user_id=b.user_id   WHERE clock_in between '".$prestrtime."' and '".$curren."' and clock_status=0 and b.status=1  ORDER BY id DESC "
```

Given below the table format

```
id  user_id     clock_in    clock_out   clock_status

1   1           1419829200   1419829800     0
2   2           1419829200   1419851689     0
3   1           1419851633   1419851677     0
```

While using this query record for each day can't be seperated.
Please help me..Waiting for your reply!

Comment: You have timestamp, so why you can't convert it to date? `date('d', $timestampFromDB)`

Comment: I need the hours ,user login for each day.The user can login more than once a day.I want the total of login hours of each day of each separate user.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate last 7 days from MYSQL query see below

```
SELECT a.user_id, b.username, a.clock_in,a.clock_out , 
DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.clock_in),FROM_UNIXTIME(a.clock_out)) 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "clock_history a 
left join " . DB_PREFIX . "user b on a.user_id=b.user_id   
WHERE clock_in between UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())
and clock_status=0 and b.status=1  
ORDER BY id DESC
```

**UPDATE**
`DATE_DIFF()` function works with two date not timestamps, so convert timestamps to dates using `FROM_UNIXTIME()` function

```
DATEDIFF(a.clock_in,a.clock_out)
```

to

```
#it return days, if you need hours then `/24` of total days
DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.clock_in),FROM_UNIXTIME(a.clock_out))
```

Comment: The 'DATEDIFF(a.clock_in,a.clock_out' field contain NULL value

Comment: `DATEDIFF(date1, date2)` function works between two dates not timestamps... you can create format of timestamps or if no need accurate date then you can do `(a.clock_in - a.clock_out)/60/60/24 as total_days`

Comment: I need the total hours the user is logged in for each day,not the date for last 7 days

Comment: then no need `/24` use `(a.clock_in - a.clock_out)/60/60` only see updated section in answer, you can use more especially way `DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.clock_in),FROM_UNIXTIME(a.clock_out)) / 24 as total_hours`

Comment: it returns empty result @Girish

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
SELECT a.user_id, b.username, a.clock_in,a.clock_out, 
DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.clock_in), FROM_UNIXTIME(a.clock_out)) as days 
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "clock_history a 
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "user b on a.user_id=b.user_id   
WHERE clock_in BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) 
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
AND clock_status=0 AND b.status=1  
ORDER BY id DESC
```

This will give you records from past 7 days, it uses mysql's built in function `NOW()` and `DATE_SUB()`.

Comment: DATEDIFF(a.clock_in,a.clock_out) function return NULL value

Comment: use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to convert the timestamp values in a.clock_in & a.clock_out to a date format which `DATEDIFF` can easily recognize and return the no. of days. 
    
`DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(a.clock_in), FROM_UNIXTIME(a.clock_out)) as days`